# Grunt-watch livereload does not work with compiled files (stylus, jade, etc.)

Tags: css, gruntjs, pug, stylus, livereload

My livereload is "working" in that it live reloads the page when a file is changed, but only if I modify the file directly. If the file is generated through the grunt stylus or jade compiler, nothing happens.

When I look at grunt with verbose turned on, the `Live reloading root.css...` line appears only if I save `root.css` directly. If `root.css` is modified through the stylus compiler, the line does not appear. It's as if watch doesn't detect the file has been changed if it's changed through a compiler. This same issue occurs with jade as well.

Here's my stylus task (trimmed):

```
    stylus: {
        options: {
            compress: false,
            use: [
                require('autoprefixer-stylus')
            ]
        },
        src: [
            'app/styl/**/*.styl'
        ],
        dest: 'build/css/root.css'
    }
```

And here's my watch task (trimmed):

```
    livereload: {
        options: {
            livereload: 1337,
        },
        files: 'build/**/*'
    },
    stylus: {
        files: [
            'app/styl/**/*.styl',
        ],
        tasks: ['stylus:dev']
    },
```

I really hope I'm just doing something stupid. I can't find any problems similar to this one.

**EDIT:**
Just in case this helps, I discovered that by changing my grunt task from running `['clean','jade:dev', 'stylus:dev', 'connect:dev', 'watch']` to only running `['connect:dev', 'watch']`, livereload works as intended once, then never again. (Modifying the css directly still works though.)

**EDIT 2:**
I was able to fix this by adding livereload to each specific task in watch, like so:

```
    livereload: {
        options: {
            livereload: 1337,
        },
        files: 'build/**/*'
    },
    stylus: {
        files: [
            'app/styl/**/*.styl',
        ],
        tasks: ['stylus:dev'],
        options: {
            livereload: 1337
        }
    },
```

As to why this works, I have no idea. If anyone can shed some light on this, it'd be much appreciated. Though to be honest, I don't know why I didn't try this earlier.

Comment: Can you try to lower debounceDelay?

Comment: Tried lowering it to 100. No change in behavior.

Comment: Sorry. No more ideas. As a workaround you can try to generate the file to a temp place and copy it to its final place in a second step with grunt-copy. But this is also a guess only...

Comment: And you've checked manually that the compiler indeed modifies the destination file?

Comment: @Shawn Yes I have. My test code is toggling the body color between black and white. When I save `root.styl` with `background black`, it indeed updates `root.css` to `background: #000`.

Comment: What if you change the name of the `stylus` "subtask" when configuring `watch`? Use something you don't use elsewhere, like `styles`.

Comment: @Shawn That didn't change the behavior, but I've edited my question above to include what I found fixed it. I have no idea why though, so any help as to the cause of the problem, and why doing what I did fixed it would be fantastic.

Comment: Thanks @Madgvox although it is not the best solution, it worked well, hopefully someone might be able to answer this thread sometime